# RubyMacmalloc: *** error for object 0x802600: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: ruby, macos, rhomobile, rhodes

I am trying to generate the android/IOS build of Rhomobile. I tried generating it from both command line and Rhostudio.

Getting this error:
RubyMac(24369,0xa9a9e1c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x802600: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I am on mac with OS as high Sierra(10.13.1). While googling, I noticed RubyMac has some problem with Sierra. There were few hacks available, I tried but didn't work.

Here is the reference link I followed.
https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/commit/35a0e37ea790b22465b9d8b3c46d9936b3ca7ef0

Please suggest.